# Update TextView on delete of item in recycleview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created a cartActivity using recycleview Adapter. The cart activity has a list of products and it's qty. I am showing this RecyclerView.Adapter in a different class.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(OrderListViewHolder personViewHolder, int i)
{

     }
```

In the activity, I have textview which shows total amount to be paid. That is coming up perfectly but when I delete an item by using the following:

```
localdb.deleteOrderItem(orderlistDetails.get(orderID).getOrderID());

        orderlistDetails.remove(orderID);
        notifyItemRemoved(orderID);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(orderID, 1);
```

The item gets deleted and RecycleListView gets refreshed. I want to refresh the total cost in textView also to be refreshed at the same time. how do I refresh the textview in the activity from the RecyclerView.Adapter class?

Is this possible? if so how to implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
((MyActivity) context).setNewPriceText(price);

//then in your activity create the function to setText
public void setNewPriceText(int price){
   myTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(myTxtView.getText().toString().trim()) - price));
}
```

Hope this helps